# Class 'Mage_Checkout_CartController' not found

Tags: magento-1.8, cart, php-5.4

I am overriding the Checkout Controller. For that I created my package Easylife and created the Checkout module.  The code for that is below:

`magento\app\etc\modules\Easylife_Checkout.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_Checkout>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Checkout/>
            </depends>
        </Easylife_Checkout>
    </modules>
</config>
```

and `magento\app\code\local\Easylife\Checkout\controllers\CartController.php`

```
<?php

class Easylife_Checkout_CartController extends Mage_Checkout_CartController
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this
            ->loadLayout()
            ->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session')
            ->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session')
            ->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle($this->__('Shopping Cart'));

        if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn())
        {
            $this->_redirect('customer/account/login'); // add login form
        }

        $this->renderLayout();
    }

}
```

and `magento\app\code\local\Easylife\Checkout\etc\config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_Checkout>
            <version>1.6.0.1</version>
        </Easylife_Checkout>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <checkout>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Easylife_Checkout</module>
                    <frontName>checkout</frontName>
                </args>
            </checkout>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

but it's returning an error `Class 'Mage_Checkout_CartController' not found` when I hit the cart link button in header link.

Is this procedure correct?

If this is wrong can you tell me how to override that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include this line in `app\code\local\Easylife\Checkout\controllers\CartController.php` before the class declaration.

```
require_once 'Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php';
```

This is needed because the controller classes are not autoloaded like the rest of the classes are.
You may also want to change the way you defined your frontend router. You might get in trouble if you just declare the same route name for 2 modules.
So change this:

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <checkout>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Easylife_Checkout</module>
                <frontName>checkout</frontName>
            </args>
        </checkout>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

To this:

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <checkout>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Easylife_Checkout before="Mage_Checkout">Easylife_Checkout</Easylife_Checkout>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </checkout>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

This will tell magento to look for a controller when the request starts with `checkout/` in your module before looking in the `Mage_Checkout` module.

Comment: now displaying `checkout\cart` page. see my posted question `CartController.php` I have override if user not login I redirected login this is not working why?

Comment: ok thank you working fine I had small mistake. now I correct my self.

Comment: Erm, `</Crap_Mod2>`??

Comment: @jongosi...oups. sorry about that. Copy paste mistake :).